# power distribution loss of negative on 120v circut

Tags: wiring

If you loose the negative wire on a 120v circuit, can you use the negative going to a different circuit breaker panel supplying  power to a different part of the building if the load is not high on that panel?

Comment: Neutral not negative... It has neutral potential in relation to ground. Even in DC, there's a major difference between Ground and Negative. Some devices have a positive ground even.

Answer (score 1):

No. No, you cannot.

Also, if you're talking about [Alternating Current (AC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current) it's not a *negative* wire, it's a grounded conductor or "neutral" wire.